# Negative currency number XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, currency, string-formatting

I have a little problem with the current format of my negative currency number.
Here's a screenshot resuming my situation.

1. This is how I'm using the StringFormat in my binding. (BTW, I tried only {0:C})
2. As expected
3. The current settings of my computer for the negative currency number
   4.
4. The result when I'm running my application

[image]

Why the result isn't -0,08 $ ?

Any ideas of how I should proceed?

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to resolve the problem with a converter, here's the result :

- I found that the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` was not the same as the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, so I fixed it in my App.xaml.cs. Unfortunately, same result.
- I tried to display my values through a converter to see if I could debug the problem. The fact is that the culture received in the parameters of the `Convert` method was okay, but its `CurrentNegativePattern` was not the same as in the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. That's probably the reason why I have this problem. for the moment, I'll use this : `return ((double)value).ToString("C2", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);` in the `Convert` method of my converter.

Comment: +1 - Not sure either, probably somehow related to the culture used.  Maybe a way to specify that in the XAML?  http://shujaatsiddiqi.blogspot.com/2010/08/wpf-localization-stringformat-for.html shows how to force the current culture in the constructor for the window - maybe give that a shot for debugging purposes.

Comment: +1 for overriding the `LanguageProperty`; didn't know that.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I was looking for. But thanks for the tip !

Comment: @esylvestre: That's why I didn't give it as an answer.  I was just wondering if it worked, cause it might give you a clue to where to go next.

Comment: Stupid question: Are you binding negative value?

Comment: Ever find anything on this other than a converter?

Comment: @JonahKunz didn't have to change it, so I didn't look for another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `CurrentCulture` to `CurrentUICulture`:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag))
);
```

Please note though that this may not use your regional settings. The `CultureInfo` object does describe your regional settings, but what you're doing with the `IetfLanguageTag` is extracting that to a specific culture. That culture does not have the adjustments you've made to your regional settings.

Alternatively, you can have a look at the `ConvertCulture` option of the binding. This actually does take a `CultureInfo`.

Comment: That is because you have no way of specifying the specifics of the culture, and it uses the generic settings of the culture. I think the only way you can achieve this is using the `ConverterCulture` property of the binding, but I think this will be a pain to apply. This actually does take a `CultureInfo`, but it doesn't look easy to use.

Comment: So what do you think avout the solution I'm currently using (see update in my main post -I'm talking about a Converter using the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture- )?

Comment: Yeah, like you said, OK. But I still want the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx